# Why does my Visual Studio 2017 compiler not recognize C++17 type deduction guides

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, c++17, type-deduction, template-argument-deduction

My Visual Studio 2017 won´t recognize the type deduction guide in this code and won´t compile:

```
template<typename T>
class Example{
public:
    Example(T& pVal)
        :val(pVal){}
    T& val;
};
//type deduction guide for Example constructor
template<typename T>
Example(T&)->Example<T>;
```

Even though, according to my [sources](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-3fVp0U4xi0&feature=youtu.be), this should be the correct syntax for a C++17 type deduction guide and it is defined in the same scope as the class it should guide.

How can I modify my Visual Studio C++ compiler to recognize this feature?

Comment: Did you check C++1z support for your version of Visual Studio? Compilers have to get features added. They aren't magically made aware of new standard revisions.

Comment: [Case and point](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/05/10/c17-features-in-vs-2017-3/): **Template argument deduction for class templates** status - NO.

Comment: And here's the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/visual-cpp-language-conformance) and the (usually up-to-date) [page from cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support)

Comment: But there obviously are compilers which do already support these features. Can I modify Visual studio to use any of these compilers?

Comment: Neither page has an entry on deduction guides. Guess it's not high on the list of priorities.

Comment: You might be able to [use clang or gcc](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/03/07/use-any-c-compiler-with-visual-studio/). Alternatively just drop Visual Studio.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I dont come to stackoverflow because I know how it works, but because I need help with something. And this is not a topic you can easily look up. I dont know much about compilers, I dont know much about the development of visual studio. Thats why I ASK here. Thats what this is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade your compiler.

Well wait first.  Reading the release notes, I don't see it in Update 3, 4 or the preview for 5.

[c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) support in MSVC remains experimental and incomplete.  [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) and [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) support merely remains incomplete (mostly around SFINAE), but is no longer experimental.

Visual studio ships with a hybrid clang and microsoft compiler.  [clang-c2](/questions/tagged/clang-c2) should support this when MSVC updates it to the clang 5.0 compiler (last I checked it was 3.8).

[Clang 5 LLVM](http://releases.llvm.org/download.html) for windows can be downloaded, but its integration with visual studio is challenging and some things you want to do may simply not work.  But it does support deduction guides.

Modifying visual studio to use Clang 5 is more than a bit of work.  One thing you could do is to write a system to build both vcproj and makefile from some dependency and project description files.  Use the makefiles to build, and the vcproj simply to enable intellisense (which won't understand your deduction guides I believe) when editing code.  (I've worked at places that do the rough equivalent of this combinations of python, batch files, makefiles themselves, and sometimes even C#).

This (creating your own build chain) is a project in and of itself.

Another approach I've seen work is to generate the *vcproj* files, and hand-craft the *makefile*s.  If your project directory structure is simple enough, writing a vcproj good enough to do intellisense isn't going to be hard.

Comment: Intel C++ compiler has VS integration from the box and also does a better job in C++14/17 field. It lacks some features (or is buggy on some constructs) though.

Comment: Unfortunately, Clang/C2 will not receive any updates https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/34693/clangc2-version-getting-old.html#reply-167512